# Why can I select all of the radio buttons in my HTML code?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have created radio buttons in HTML. But when I select a radio button and then select another radio button, both radio buttons are selected.

I want to select a radio button and then the other radio buttons will not be selected.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is an image showing all radio buttons selected:

[image]

Here is my code:

```html
<tr>
  <td class="style10"><label>Subject Knowledge: </label></td>
  <td class="style10">
    <input id="Radio1" type="radio" /><span>1</span>
    <input id="Radio2" type="radio" /><span>2</span>
    <input id="Radio3" type="radio" /><span>3</span>
    <input id="Radio4" type="radio" /><span>4</span>
    <input id="Radio5" type="radio" /><span>5</span>
    <p>Please tick the level of subject knowledge (1 = low to 5 = high)</p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give Same name to all radio buttons.
Try This

```html
<tr>
<td class="style10"><label>Subject Knowledge: </label></td>
<td class="style10">
    <input id="Radio1"  type="radio" name="somename" /><span>1</span>
    <input id="Radio2" type="radio" name="somename"/><span>2</span>
    <input id="Radio3" type="radio" name="somename"/><span>3</span>
    <input id="Radio4" type="radio" name="somename"/><span>4</span>
    <input id="Radio5" type="radio" name="somename"/><span>5</span>
    <p>Please tick the level of subject knowledge (1 = low to 5 = high)</p></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `name` attribute to your radio buttons.

If two radio buttons have the same name, only one could be selected.

```
<tr>
<td class="style10"><label>Subject Knowledge: </label></td>
<td class="style10">
    <input id="Radio1" name="myName" type="radio"  /><span>1</span>
    <input id="Radio2" name="myName" type="radio" /><span>2</span>
    <input id="Radio3" name="myName" type="radio" /><span>3</span>
    <input id="Radio4" name="myName" type="radio" /><span>4</span>
    <input id="Radio5" name="myName" type="radio" /><span>5</span>
    <p>Please tick the level of subject knowledge (1 = low to 5 = high)</p></td>
</tr>
```

---

**Edit**

To improve your code, you also could:

- Add a `label` tag to enable selection on label click
- Add a `value` attribute

Here is an example:

```
<td class="style10"><label>Subject Knowledge: </label></td>
<td class="style10">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="myName" value="1" />
        <span>1</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="myName" value="2" />
        <span>2</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="myName" value="3" />
        <span>3</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="myName" value="4" />
        <span>4</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="myName" value="5" />
        <span>5</span>
    </label>
    <p>Please tick the level of subject knowledge (1 = low to 5 = high)</p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make radio button group for selecting only one, you must give same name for all radio buttons like as follows:

```
<tr>
 <td class="style10"><label>Subject Knowledge: </label></td>
 <td class="style10">
  <input id="Radio1" name="rdSubKnowledge" type="radio"  /><span>1</span>
  <input id="Radio2" name="rdSubKnowledge" type="radio" /><span>2</span>
  <input id="Radio3" name="rdSubKnowledge" type="radio" /><span>3</span>
  <input id="Radio4" name="rdSubKnowledge" type="radio" /><span>4</span>
  <input id="Radio5" name="rdSubKnowledge" type="radio" /><span>5</span>
  <p>Please tick the level of subject knowledge (1 = low to 5 = high)</p>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify same name for the radio button group, for example:

```
<div>
    <input name="Sport" type="radio"  /><span>Basketball</span>
    <input  name="Sport" type="radio" /><span>Volleyball</span>
    <input  name="Sport" type="radio" /><span>Rugby</span>
    <input  name="Sport" type="radio" /><span>Football</span>
    <input  name="Sport" type="radio" /><span>Tennis</span>
</div>
```